# Python Selenium Webdriver accesing data

Tags: python, html, selenium-webdriver

[HTML CODE OF WEBSITE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YGyR1.png) - click here

I was trying to acces **9 months ago**  using selenium but always ended up with error.

```py
def function1(nick_hraca):
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    base_url = "https://lichess.org/@/" + nick_hraca

    driver.get(base_url)
    driver.minimize_window()

    #activity = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="us_profile"]/div[2]/div/div/p[2]/time')
    #print(activity.get_attribute(""))

    activity = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,"time")
    print(activity.get_attribute("set"))

    games = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="main-wrap"]/main/div/div[5]/a[2]')
    
    #print(activity.text)
    print(games.text)

    time.sleep(5)

    driver.quit()
```

Can someone help me ?
Thanks in advance

I tried this one but wasnt working

```py
#activity = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="us_profile"]/div[2]/div/div/p[2]/time')
#print(activity.get_attribute("set"))
```

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to find `class = "time"` with `driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,"time")`.
But the target element's attribute is `class = "set"`.

And `9 months ago` is text of the element.
You can get it with `.text` property.

try

```py
activity = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,"set")
print(activity.text)
```

or

```py
activity = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//time")
print(activity.text)
```